# Visualforce - rerender all my tabs

Tags: visualforce, community

Let me describe my situation.  On the account record page, I've a button that users can click and it will takes them to my VF page as well as passing the account Id to my page.  Once on the VF page users are asked to select a child record.  I then captured the child record Id and pass it into my SOQL statements when a command button is pressed.  But all my SOQL statements are within my constructor. Now that I have the child record id, How do I re-execute my constructor again so that the data are populated into all my tabs (5)?  I would show codes but it is so long.  Thanks for the helps.

```
public void processSelectedCBR() {
selectedCBRs = new List<CBR__c>();

    for(wrapCBR wrapCBRObj : wrapCBRList) {
        if(wrapCBRObj.selected == true) {
            //Get Report Id when user selected report
            String  ReportId = wrapCBRObj.rep.Id;
            query();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you move your queries to a separate method that you can call from the constructor and from the code run when the user selects the child record:

```
public class MyController {
    public MyController() {
        query(null);
    }
    public void processSelectedCBR() {
        for(wrapCBR wrapCBRObj : wrapCBRList) {
        if (wrapCBRObj.selected == true) {
            // Get Report Id when user selected report
            Id reportId = wrapCBRObj.rep.Id;
            query(reportId);
            break;
        }
        return null
    }
    private void query(Id reportId) {
        // Move all your queries to here
        // Figure out what to do when reportId is both null and not null
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith C, it doesn't seem to work.  May be I'm capturing the child record id incorrectly.  Can you help take a look at my method?  Thanks

Comment: @user7123 You'll need to learn more about the scope of variables to get very far here. I've changed my answer to illustrate one approach, but if you want to do other things with the selected ID you should probably make it a field of the class.